# How can I make an anchor in a list the same with as a surrounding div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

This long text inside an anchor link is cropped by styles. I need to set width of the anchor to be the same as div 2. When screen is wide, it should be inline.

When screen become smaller, it should shrink to some minimum width, and next - wrap. And, when it wrapped, the width again must be 100%

Problem with this cropped text inside the anchor is that I can't set `flex: 0 1 300px` - it doesn't work. Also, I can't set fixed width because I need it to be flexible. If I set width in % it's not flexible, also. Just same as width in px.

How can I copy width from div_2 to the anchor or make the anchor also flexible?

```css
content {
  display: flex;
}

div 1 {
  flex: 1 0 600px;
}

div 2 {
  flex: 0 1 300px;
}

a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<content>
  <div 1>
    <div 2>
      <ul>
        <li><a>some long-very long text ... etc</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</content>
```

Comment: Please revise the demo above so it shows your problem. `<div 1>` is not valid HTML. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to wrap, nowrap is a strange option to choose.  Also, your html is off a bit.  Check out below and let me know if this is what you are looking for.

```css
content {
  display: flex;
}

#a1 {
  flex: 1 0 ;
}

#a2 {
  flex: 0 1 ;
  border:1px solid red;
  
}

a {
  white-space: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<content>
  <div id='a1'>
    <div id='a2'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">some long-very long text ............................... etc</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</content>
```